# How to resolve lifelink with multiple blockers?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-arena

I have a 4/4 with lifelink with x6 +1/+1 counters for a total power/toughness of 10/10.

My opponent declared 3 blockers:

- 4/4
- 4/4
- 2/1

Do I get 10 life for each blocker?

Answer (score 9):

No, you get life equal to the *total damage dealt*. Your creature has 10 power, so it will deal 10 damage *in total* and you'll gain 10 life. The way that damage is split up between multiple blocking creatures doesn't matter.

Comment: This is correct. Defending creature's toughness doesn't matter. If he chump blocks with a 1/1, you still get 10 life.

Answer (score 2):

Cadence has already [answered](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/392042/222632) this question. The relevant rules are:

> 702.15b. Damage dealt by a source with lifelink causes that source's controller, or its owner if it has no controller, to gain that much
> life (in addition to any other results that damage causes).

and:

> 510.1c  A blocked creature assigns its combat damage to the creatures blocking it. If no creatures are currently blocking it (if, for
> example, they were destroyed or removed from combat), it assigns no
> combat damage. If exactly one creature is blocking it, it assigns all
> its combat damage to that creature. If two or more creatures are
> blocking it, it assigns its combat damage to those creatures according
> to the damage assignment order announced for it. This may allow the
> blocked creature to divide its combat damage. However, it can’t assign
> combat damage to a creature that’s blocking it unless, when combat
> damage assignments are complete, each creature that precedes that
> blocking creature in its order is assigned lethal damage. When
> checking for assigned lethal damage, take into account damage already
> marked on the creature and damage from other creatures that’s being
> assigned during the same combat damage step, but not any abilities or
> effects that might change the amount of damage that’s actually dealt.
> An amount of damage that’s greater than a creature’s lethal damage may
> be assigned to it.